# Retrieve tables and colums used in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a big amount of huge SQL statements (1k+ lines each). Is there any way to get a list of the tables and columns used by a specific SQL statement?

I need this to cleanup unused columns (don't ask me why).

RDBMS: Oracle 11gR2

For example:

```
SELECT t1.col1,t1.col2,t2.col3
  from table1 t1, table2 t2, table3 t3
where t1.col1=t3.col1
  and t3.col2=t2.col1
```

Output (proposal only):

```
TABLE1 COL1
TABLE1 COL2
TABLE2 COL1
TABLE2 COL3
TABLE3 COL1
TABLE3 COL2
```

**Edit 1:**
I've just created view based on `select` and I can read about tables from `ALL_DEPENDENCES` view. Maybe is another way to look up for columns also ?

Comment: I don't think so. You will have to go through SQL code and clean it up accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a list of the tables used by a particular SQL statement, you can

- create a view with that SQL statement
- query the system view `USER_DEPENDENCIES` to get a list of tables referenced in that view
- drop the view

e.g.

```
CREATE VIEW VW1 AS
SELECT t1.col1,t1.col2,t2.col3
FROM table1 t1, table2 t2, table3 t3
where t1.col1=t3.col1
  and t3.col2=t2.col1;
```

and then

```
select referenced_owner, referenced_name 
from user_dependencies 
where name = 'VW1';
```

As for the list of the used columns, I guess you'll have to do the parsing yourself.

Comment: I have just firuge this in the same way :). Maybe You have idea for columns ?

Comment: @WBAR - `SELECT * FROM USER_TAB_COLS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'name-of-your-view'`